# How to print data from sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I don't understand how I would print the data that I have queried from a database.

For example:

```
def display_stock(self):
    with sqlite3.connect("db_name.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE StockLevel > 0"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
```

So I created this function to select all products in a database that are still in stock. But how do I display these products in the database to the user?

Comment: The same way data from a file would be printed. Where the data comes from is not relevant. So the question is "How to READ data from SQLite?" and there are *many* questions and tutorials about that.

Comment: Read [cursor-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

Comment: BTW, you don't need to commit if you're just reading data.

Comment: You seem to have missed the examples in Pythons [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've executed a query, you need to fetch the result. Either with [`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) (fetches one result row), [`fetchmany`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany) (fetches multiple rows) or [`fetchall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) fetches all of them. E.g.:

```
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the cursor as an iterator, or get results from the cursor using `fetchone()` or `fetchall()`

ie:

`print(cursor.fetchone())`

If you are only executing a SELECT statement, you don't need to commit.